# How to modify a String using loops and StringBuilder

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program which prints a table of contents and develops the necessary code to read in a chapter name and
page number until “****” is entered. The outputted String needs to be the same length and left and right justified.

How can I add dots in between the title and page number, so that the length of each title outputted is the same size? The setEntries method is where I'm trying to do this. This is the code I have developed so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TocEntry
{
    ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>( 100 );
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public void setMinLength( int length )
    {
        minLength = length;
    } // end method setMinLength

    public void setEntries(ArrayList<String> list)
     {
        int count = 0;

        for( String i : list)
        {
            sb.append(i).append("\n");

            String str = (String) list.get(count);

            int len = str.length();

            if( len < minLength )
            sb.append(".");
            count++;
        }
    } // end method note

    public String toString()
    {
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String chapterPageEntry;
    private int minLength;
}// end class TocEntry

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Toc
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int index = 0;
        int longestChapterName = 0;

        TocEntry contents = new TocEntry();
        List entries = new ArrayList();

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        while( index < 3 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Enter chapter name: " );
            String chapterName = input.nextLine();

            if( chapterName.equals( "****" ) )
                break;

            System.out.println( "Enter starting page number of chapter: " );
            int chapterStartingPage = input.nextInt();

            String entry = chapterName + ".." + chapterStartingPage;
            entries.add( entry );

            int length = entry.length();
            longestChapterName = Math.max( length, longestChapterName );

            input.nextLine();
            index ++;
            System.out.print(entry);
        } // end while

        contents.setMinLength( longestChapterName );

        contents.setEntries( entries );

        System.out.print( contents.sb );

    } // end main
```

Comment: Consider doing your own homework.   Also, consider asking a question.

Comment: This is disrespectful to the skill and time of people who are willing to take the trouble to answer your question if you're willing to take the trouble to work at it until you get to a specific difficulty.

Comment: No need to be so harsh. He's posted some code at least so he's ahead of a lot of people. @user3344383, you won't get much joy on this as the question is very broad and there is too much to look at. If you can narrow down your problem area and ask a much more specific question that will go better for you.

Comment: I don't know why people insist on using scanners during development, when it is an unbelievable chore to have to enter in everything *every*... ***single*** ...time...

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this and Java. Been trying for hours to get this code to work that's why I posted my code for assistance.

Comment: I agree with DwB. Ask a question, don't ask us to do your work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one problem to get you started:

```
int i = 0;
while( i < list.size() )
{
   if( list.get(i).length() < minLength )
      sb.append(".");
}
```

This loop will never end, because `i` never changes: It's always and forever equal to zero. This is causing the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Increment it in the loop with `i++`.

Comment: A for loop rather than a while loop would be better.

Comment: I fixed all the syntax. The program runs fine, but how can I modify each element in the ArrayList to print the same length Strings by adding "....." inbetween the chapter title and page number?

Comment: `[number-of-dots] = [total-display-length] - [string-length-of-number] - [length-of-chapter]`. And handle if ends up being less than zero. You're going to have to show some more effort and more code and stack-traces if you expect more help.

Answer (score 1):

The general process would be to get your title string, convert the page number to a string, and then subtract the length of those two strings from the total width that you want the TOC entries to be. The result will be the number of dots you need to print between those two strings to achieve that width.

Example, say you want your total width to be 40:

```
title: "Some Chapter"     length: 12
page: "42"                length: 2
number of dots = 40 - (12 + 2) = 26

title: "Another Chapter"  length: 15
page: "200"               length: 3
number of dots = 40 - (15 + 3) = 22

Some Chapter..........................42  <- 26 dots
Another Chapter......................200  <- 22 dots
```